# ¿Como intercambiar un numero mayor con uno menor y viceversa?

Tags: java

Tengo problemas con un ejercicio de fundamentos de programacion que me pide  ingresar n numeros a un vector e intercambiar el mayor numero en la posicion del menor numero y viceversa y luego mostrarlo

```
 int a[];
        int ta;
        int menor =99999999;
        int mayor=0;
        String vi= "";
        String vf="";

        int aux=0;
        ta=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Ingrese el tamaño del vector"));

        a= new int [ta];

        for (int i=0; i<ta; i++){
           a[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el valor del vector en la posicion "+i));
            vi= vi+ "["+a[i]+"]";

             }

        for (int k=0 ; k<ta; k++){
            if (a[k]> mayor  && a[k]< menor){
                 aux =mayor;
                 menor = mayor;
                 aux= menor;



            vf= vf + "["+ a[k]+"]";

        }  
    }  
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los valores en las posiciones  iniciales son:"+vi +
                "\n  Los valores en las posiciones finales son "+vf);
    }
```

Comment: Hola Glenda. Que es lo que has intentado? Es un ejercicio simple. Necesitas saber la posición de ambos números (con un for es facil). El menor y el mayor. Cuando termines la comprobación solo los intercambias. Sería bueno que pusieras tu código para ayudarte de manera más especifica.

Comment: for (int k=0 ; k<ta; k++){
            if (a[k]> mayor  && a[k]< menor){
                 aux =mayor;
                 menor = mayor;
                 aux= menor;

Comment: tengo duda en esa parte del codigo

Comment: Hay una opción para editar tu pregunta. Puedes pegar todo el ciclo para que quede más claro. Y por lo que veo lo que estas viendo es ordenamientos, me supongo que debe ser por burbuja o lineal.

Comment: Entonces. Solo necesitas el valor mayor y menor?  Dos valores? O necesitas que todo el vector este ordenado de mayor a menor?

Comment: me pide mostrar los valores solo  con el mayor y menor intercambiado pero los demas q este igual sin ordenar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te ayudo con tu problema. Lo he hecho por ti y he comentado paso por paso.

Código:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Ejercicio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int vector[];
        int tamanoVector;
        int menor;
        int mayor;
        int posicionMenor = 0;
        int posicionMayor = 0;

        tamanoVector = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el tamaño del vector"));

        vector = new int[tamanoVector];

        // Pedimos los valores para el vector
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            vector[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el valor del vector en la posicion " + i));
        }

        // Imprimir vector para confirmar que los datos fueron guardados correctamente
        System.out.println("Vector de " + tamanoVector + " posiciones:");
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("[" + i + "] " + vector[i]);
        }

        // Asignar a mayor y menor el valor de la primera posición del arreglo
        menor = vector[0];
        mayor = vector[0];

        // (puedes usar int = i nuevamente, no habrá problemas ya que es un "scope" diferente
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            if (menor > vector[i]) {
                menor = vector[i];
                posicionMenor = i;
            }

            if (mayor < vector[i]) {
                mayor = vector[i];
                posicionMayor = i;
            }
        }

        // Imprimir el mayor y el menor
        System.out.println("\nMenor: [" + posicionMenor + "] " + menor + "\nMayor: [" + posicionMayor + "] " + mayor);

        // Cambiar posiciones en el vector
        vector[posicionMenor] = mayor;
        vector[posicionMayor] = menor;

        // Imprimir vector nuevamente con las posiciones cambiadas
        System.out.println("\nMayor y menor cambiados:");
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("[" + i + "] " + vector[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> Vector de 3 posiciones:
>
> [0] 86
>
> [1] 50
>
> [2] 12
>
> Menor: [2] 12
>
> Mayor: [0] 86
>
> Vector con mayor y menor cambiados:
>
> [0] 12
>
> [1] 50
>
> [2] 86

Si necesitas mostrar el resultado con `JOptionPane`, estoy seguro que podrás hacerlo sin problemas.

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos!.

Comment: Tu respuesta mantiene un grave error del código que quién hace la pregunta. El error es al asignar valores fijos a las vavriables `mayor` y `menor`. En caso de que se entren solo números negativos, `mayor` siempre será 0, provocando que se intercambie siempre el primer elemento del arreglo con el menor. Por el contrario, si solo se introducen valores mayores a 9999, `menor` siempre será 9999 y se intercambiará siempre el primer elemento del arreglo por el mayor. Para Solucionarlo debes asignar a ambas variables el valor del primer elemento del arreglo, ej. `int mayor = vector[0]`

Comment: @E.Betanzos tienes razón, se me ha pasado. Lo he arreglado. Gracias amigo!.

Comment: muchas gracias chicos

Comment: @GlendaGuerreroFlores si te ha ayudado mi respuesta, no olvides seleccionarla como Respuesta Elegida, saludos.

Comment: ya esta perdon, soy media atolondrada